# SQL Join And Filter By User - Multiple Joins

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm having an issue with SQL and I can't find out a solution. It seems to be simple.

I've four tables as follow : Task, User, Building and BuildingUser. 
Task - Each user can open a task which is related to a Building
User - Stores users
Building - Stores buildings
BuildingUser - Represents a relation between User and Building. It shows which user can "see" a Building. N->N

My case:

Table **Task**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TASK] 
  ( 
     [ID]          [INT] IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL, 
     [ID_USER]     [INT] NOT NULL, 
     [ID_BUILDING] [INT] NOT NULL 
  )
```

Table **Building**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[BUILDING] 
  ( 
     [ID]   [INT] IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL, 
     [NAME] [VARCHAR](50) NOT NULL 
  )
```

Table **User**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[USER] 
  ( 
     [ID]   [INT] IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL, 
     [NAME] [VARCHAR](50) NOT NULL 
  )
```

Table **BuildingUser**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[BUILDINGUSER] 
  ( 
     [ID]          [INT] IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL, 
     [ID_BUILDING] [INT] NOT NULL, 
     [ID_USER]     [INT] NOT NULL 
  )
```

**Sample Data**

***Task***

```
ID|ID_USER|ID_BUILDING
1 |1      |1
2 |1      |2
```

***User***

```
ID|Name
1 |Carlos
2 |Joao
3 |Maria
```

***Building***

```
ID|Name
1 |Rochavera
2 |San George
```

***BuildingUser***

```
ID_USER|ID_BUILDING
2      |1
3      |2
```

So, I want to transfer two task at the same time to as many users as possible. However, these users have to see all buildings of Tasks I've selected. For example, If I've selected Task.ID 1 and 2 The query must return "nothing" because I don't have a user who sees both buildings. But If I've selected just one task, like ID 1, I'd be able to transfer to User ID 2.

I've this query, but it's wrong. It was just a try.

```
SELECT DISTINCT [USER].ID, 
                [USER].NAME 
FROM   TASK 
       INNER JOIN BUILDINGUSER 
               ON BUILDINGUSER.ID_BUILDING = TASK.ID_BUILDING 
       INNER JOIN [USER] 
               ON [USER].ID = BUILDINGUSER.ID_USER 
WHERE  TASK.ID IN ( 1, 2 )
```

**EDIT**
I followed instructions below and got it working.

```
SELECT u.ID, 
       u.NAME 
FROM   TASK t 
       JOIN BUILDINGUSER bu 
         ON bu.ID_BUILDING = t.ID_BUILDING 
       JOIN [USER] u 
         ON u.ID = bu.ID_USER 
WHERE  t.ID IN ( 1, 2 ) 
       AND u.ID != t.ID_USER 
GROUP  BY u.ID, 
          u.NAME 
HAVING Count(bu.ID_BUILDING) = (SELECT Count(*) 
                                FROM   TASK t2 
                                WHERE  t2.ID IN ( 1, 2 ))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a "set-within-sets" query.  You are looking for a all members of a group (the tasks) within a set.

I advocate solving this by using aggregation and putting the logic in the `having` clause:

```
select u.id, u.name
from Task t join
     BuildingUser bu
     ON bu.ID_BUILDING = t.ID_BUILDING join
     [User] u
     ON u.ID = bu.ID_USER 
group by u.id, u.name
having sum(case when t.id = 1 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and  -- Any rows with taskid = 1 ?
       sum(case when t.id = 2 then 1 else 0 end) > 0;     -- Any rows with taskid = 2 ?
```

The advantage of this approach is that it is easy to generalize.  Say you wanted tasks 1 and 2 *but not* 3.  The `having` clause changes to:

```
having sum(case when t.id = 1 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when t.id = 2 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when t.id = 3 then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

Comment: I got it. But I need something dynamic. Like, I could have IDs 5,8,65 instead of 1,2

Comment: @Gandarez . . . For each id, you can construct the `sum(case . . . )` statement to construct the `having` clause.  Otherwise, what would you consider "dynamic"?

Comment: I consider it dynamic becuase I need to make a query that I'll use as generic. I've been not clear, Have I? Imagine, I've more than 1000 IDs to check, How can I implement this query?